# pktgen: Not able to send vlan tagged traffic using .lua script

Tags: dpdk

I need right format for enabling vlan while sending traffic through lua script,
following format is working without error, but it send traffic without vlan tag, not sure what is missing here, please help

```
pktgen.range.dst_mac("0", "start", "00:00:5e:00:01:00");
pktgen.range.src_mac("0", "start", "00:16:00:01:00:01");
pktgen.range.src_mac("0", "inc", "00:00:00:00:00:01");
pktgen.range.src_mac("0", "min", "00:16:00:01:00:01");
pktgen.range.src_mac("0", "max", "00:16:00:01:00:cd");
pktgen.range.src_ip("0", "start", "1.1.1.1");
pktgen.range.src_ip("0", "inc", "0.0.0.0");
pktgen.range.src_ip("0", "mint", "1.1.1.1");
pktgen.range.src_ip("0", "max", "1.1.1.1");
pktgen.range.dst_ip("0", "start", "1.1.1.2");
pktgen.range.dst_ip("0", "inc", "0.0.0.0");
pktgen.range.dst_ip("0", "mint", "1.1.1.2");
pktgen.range.dst_ip("0", "max", "1.1.1.2");
pktgen.set_type("0", "ipv4");
pktgen.set_proto("0", "udp");
pktgen.set("0", "size", 1024);
pktgen.set("0", "rate", 0.25);
pktgen.set("0", "burst", 1);
pktgen.set_range("all", "on");
pktgen.vlanid("0", 9);
local port ="0";
pktgen.start(port);
```

Comment: couple of call out, you are using `range` but I do not see it enabled. You want to use `vlan` but not enabling it. Please relook into the script or simply execute the same and `save` the settings to get the necessary settings.

Comment: tested and updated with the answer, if you find the answer helpful accept and upvote

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the `vlan` enable is not triggered in the LUA scripts which causes VLAN not to be enabled. I have modified the above lua script to enable vlan,

please find the details below

```
package.path = package.path ..";?.lua;test/?.lua;app/?.lua;"
require "Pktgen"

-- enable vlan feature, default setting is disabled.
pktgen.vlan("all", "enable");

pktgen.range.dst_mac("0", "start", "00:00:5e:00:01:00");
pktgen.range.src_mac("0", "start", "00:16:00:01:00:01");
pktgen.range.src_mac("0", "inc", "00:00:00:00:00:01");
pktgen.range.src_mac("0", "min", "00:16:00:01:00:01");
pktgen.range.src_mac("0", "max", "00:16:00:01:00:cd");
pktgen.range.src_ip("0", "start", "1.1.1.1");
pktgen.range.src_ip("0", "inc", "0.0.0.0");
pktgen.range.src_ip("0", "mint", "1.1.1.1");
pktgen.range.src_ip("0", "max", "1.1.1.1");
pktgen.range.dst_ip("0", "start", "1.1.1.2");
pktgen.range.dst_ip("0", "inc", "0.0.0.0");
pktgen.range.dst_ip("0", "mint", "1.1.1.2");
pktgen.range.dst_ip("0", "max", "1.1.1.2");
pktgen.set_type("0", "ipv4");
pktgen.set_proto("0", "udp");
pktgen.set("0", "size", 1024);
pktgen.set("0", "rate", 0.25);
pktgen.set("0", "burst", 1);
pktgen.set_range("all", "on");
pktgen.vlanid("0", 9);
pktgen.start(port);
```

Note:

1. there are 2 options in pktgen to run the lua ***from command line use option -f, and within interactive mode use script option***.
2. results for without running the script (left side) and result for after running the script (right side) shared in the image below

[image]